# Scapy with eventlet raises "Child died unexpectedly. Packets may have not been sent"

Tags: python-3.x, celery, scapy, eventlet

I've been doing some work on port scanning. I'm trying to do a SYN scan (send SYN and and cut the cord if I get an SYN-ACK), and the operation worked perfect on single thread.

When trying to run it using eventlet (on a Celery threaded worker), I get the following exception when running it:

```
Child died unexpectedly. Packets may have not been sent
```

The following is my code that raises the issue:

```
    def pscan(dest_ip, dest_port):
        packet = IP(dst=dest_ip) / TCP(dport=int(dest_port), flags='S')
        res = sr1(packet, verbose=False, timeout=1)

        if res and res.haslayer(TCP):
            if res[TCP].flags == 18: # SYN-ACK flag
                return True

        return False
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to get some information out of dying child. Was it killed by kernel? Is it possible to get coredump? Most likely, it left Python traceback.

Comment: How do I get a coredump/traceback information?

Comment: Use Google or your favourite search engine to find information on debugging Python programs.

Comment: Now I get what you've ment regarding traceback. I get only that message. Regarding coredump, WDYM?

Comment: I mean use search.

You have to do work before you get real error details. scapy child calls some function and it either raises exception or OS kills process. In first case scapy hides useful traceback. If OS kills process, it is possible to configure it to leave coredump. Assuming UNIX-like OS.

Comment: I really mean web search https://www.google.com/search?q=coredump
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=coredump+python